# defining a name value lookup in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a hash/object in typescript.  The keys into the hash are dynamic and normally a number.  the values in the typescript are the always the same Interface type.  So it would look something like this.

> hsh = { 100: {a:3, b:'s'}, 200: {a:77, b:'d'} }

How would I define hsh so I make sure that a value with a missing key is never put in it.

How would I define this in typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript this is called an [index type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

```
type MyType = {
  a: string
  b: number
}

type MyHash = {
  [index: number]: MyType
}

const hash: MyHash = {
  100: { a: 'hello', b: 3 }
}
```

Accessing an object of type MyHash with anything but a number will result in a compile time error.

If you have a particular type that you want to use as keys, for example the numbers 100 and 200, then you can use a [mapped type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

```
type MyKeys = 100 | 200

type MyHash = {
  [key in MyKeys]: MyType
}
```

This can be especially useful in combination with `const enums`. It is so useful that in my project I often use a type like this:

```
const enum KeyTypes = {
  ONE_HUNDRED,
  TWO_HUNDRED
}

type MappedType<K, V> = {
  [key in K]: V
}

type SomeMappedType = MappedType<KeyTypes, string>
```

*Note: this only works for string keys prior to ts 2.9, for 2.9 an over you can use number, symbol or string as I have above*

Comment: Thanks Ziggy. Your typescript fu is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do do it from what I understand:

```
type Char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | ... ; // all possible values for b

interface InnerHash {
    a: number,
    b: Char
}

interface Hsh {
    [index: number]: InnerHash
};

const ok: Hsh = {
    100: {a: 50, b: 'a'}, 
    200: {b: 'c', a: 10}
};

const noOk1: Hsh = {
    100: {a: 50, b: 'a'}, 
    200: {b: 'c'}
};

const notOk2: Hsh = {
    100: {a: 50, b: 'd'}
};

const notOk3: Hsh = {
    1000: {
        c: 'foo'
    }
};
```

Compiling I get:

```
$ tsc
src/so.ts(17,7): error TS2322: Type '{ 100: { a: number; b: "a"; }; 200: { b: "c"; }; }' isnot assignable to type 'Hsh'.
  Property '200' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ b: "c"; }' is not assignable to type 'InnerHash'.
      Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: "c"; }'.
src/so.ts(22,7): error TS2322: Type '{ 100: { a: number; b: "d"; }; }' is not assignable totype 'Hsh'.
  Property '100' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ a: number; b: "d"; }' is not assignable to type 'InnerHash'.
      Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
        Type '"d"' is not assignable to type 'char'.
src/so.ts(28,9): error TS2322: Type '{ 1000: { c: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Hsh'.
  Property '1000' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InnerHash'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type 'InnerHash'.
```